# Getting Registered App Display Name from an App Id

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure App Id which I have obtained from a token. I would like to get the display name of the application using C# so that I can add it to logs and Application Insights custom properties for a request. It is obviously more human-readable than an Id hence my need.

When I go into the portal I can go to the app registrations and type the AppId in and it shows me the name, so clearly it can be obtained (I can see from the URL https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/applications/?api-version=2.0&$top=40&$filter=appId%20eq%20%27MYAPPID%27), but how do I get this information programmatically in C#?

I could maintain my own lookup table somewhere which converts app ids to names, but this seems pointless when the information is obviously available at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the information about your application in your c# application, you can use  [Microsoft.Graph.Beta](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet) to call the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http). For example

**Register a new application using the Azure portal**

1. Sign in to the Azure portal using either a work or school account or
   a personal Microsoft account.
2. If your account gives you access to more than one tenant, select your account in the top right corner, and set your portal session to the Azure AD tenant that you want.
3. In the left-hand navigation pane, select the Azure Active Directory service, and then select App registrations > New registration.

**Configure Microsoft Graph permissions you need for your application** 
[image]

**Code**

```
    /*  
          install Microsoft.Graph.Beta
          install Microsoft.Graph.COre
          install Microsoft.Graph.Beta.Auth
        */
        string clientId = "your application id";
        string appKey = "your client secret";
        string tenantId = "your tenant id";
     IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = 
        ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(clientId)
                .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                .WithClientSecret(appKey)
                .Build();

                ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new 
                ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);
                var apps = graphClient.Applications.Request().Filter("appId eq \'you application id\'").GetAsync().Result; 

             foreach(var app in apps){

                 Console.WriteLine(app.DisplayName);
             }
```

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?toc=.%2Fref%2Ftoc.json&view=graph-rest-beta)

Comment: @Rob  If the answer is useful you could accept it to help others. Thanks and happy coding!

Comment: where does graphClient come from?

Comment: You can use the code ```GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );``` to create it.

Comment: I did that but graphClient.Applications is not available. Does the latest version not support this? Using these versions:   <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" version="1.0.0-preview.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net461" />

Comment: You need to install package ```Microsoft.Graph.Beta``` if you want to get applications with Graph API. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Getting: Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Authorization_RequestDenied. Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. I have added 
Directory.AccessAsUser.All (Access the directory as the signed-in user) and User.Read (Sign in and read user profile) to my app. What else do I need?

Comment: Regarding the permission, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

Comment: Just for the record, this is what I used:   <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" version="1.0.0-preview.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Beta" version="0.7.0-preview" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.17.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="3.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />